# What is the definition of duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, exact-duplicates

Sometimes it happens that the answer to a question is contained in the answer to a **different** question.

Should the former question be closed as a duplicate?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430257/proving-frac-vecv-vert-vert-vecv-vert-vert-1-quad-vecv-ne-vec0)'s an example, (read the comments). I've encountered more, but I don't think more examples are needed to make my point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that we should be careful when closing as duplicates of
more general questions; and that it is quite often not easy to
decide.

Even if it is true that the more general question answers the less
general one, there might be easier answer to less general
question. By closing question we might prevent MSE users from
posting an easier answer (which does not apply to the more general
question).

Since you posted example with integrals: I would have no problem
with closing $\int 2x+1 \,\mathrm{d}x$ as a duplicate of $\int
ax+b \,\mathrm{d}x$ or even $\int P(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$, $P$ being a
polynomial. But if we a questions asking [about $\int P(\sin
x)\,\mathrm{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx),
with answers explaining [Weierstrass
substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution),
we should not close $\int \cos^2x+\sin^2x \,\mathrm{d}x$ as a
duplicate. Many integrals including $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ might
have much simpler solution than using Weierstrass substitution; if
we close all of them as a duplicate of the more general questions,
it is true that the more general questions answers them, but we
have provided OP with a much more difficult answer than he could
have obtained if the questions would not have been closed.

Comment: Good point.${{}}$

Answer (score 4):

In principle, I'd say not. It prohibits giving answers to the newer question.

If the other question is linked in the comments, that puts it in the "Linked" section. If more than this is deemed appropriate, perhaps a CW answer pointing to (the relevant part of) the answer to the other question can be posted.

---

In general, my condition for marking duplicate is:

> Any answer to the old question will (mutatis mutandis) answer the new question.

This includes cases where the old question is more general; if OP doesn't understand the answers, they can edit to make this clear, and I'll support reopening (for the nature of the question will have changed to a follow-up question).

Of course, in specific cases I may deviate from the above as I deem fit.

Comment: I think you're contradicting yourself, depending on what exactly you mean with `This includes cases where the old question is more general`. If *question 1* is strictly more general than *question 2* and *answer 1* answers *question 1* perfectly, then *answer 1* will **not** mutatis mutadins answer *question 2*, as it will exceed it.

Comment: I meant "more general" as in "What is $\int(a+bx)^m \,\mathrm dx$?" encompassing "What is $\int(1+2x)^4\,\mathrm dx$?". It is precisely because one can argue this to fall outside of _mutatis mutandis_ that I included a remark about it.

Comment: I stand by my statement, I don't think those cases are *included* in the mutatis mutandis case.